# trouble with array

Tags: php, arrays

I am creating a export tool for excel and I am having an issue with my array.

When I go to print I see just A's?

Code:

```
$num = $_POST['num'];
    for($i =0; $i< $num; $i++){
    $firstname =  $_POST['firstnameexport'];
    $lastname = $_POST['lastnameexport'];
    $email = $_POST['emailexport'];
    $phone = $_POST['phoneexport'];
    $data = array(
    array("firstname" => $firstname[$i] , "lastname" => $lastname[$i], "email" => $email[$i], "phone" => $phone[$i])
    );
    print_r($firstname[$i]);
    }
```

it would print:

```
Afirstname  lastname    email   phone
A   A   A   A
```

values are being passed through form

Here is code:

```
$memberfirstnamearray  = array($j => $memberfirstname);
                                    $memberlastnamearray  = array($j => $memberlastname);
                                    $memberphonearray  = array($j => $memberphone);
                                    $memberemailarray  = array($j => $memberemail);

                                    $j++;
                                    $i++;
```

i and j = 0 in beginning

```
<input type='hidden' name='firstnameexport' value='$memberfirstnamearray' />
                                        <input type='hidden' name='lastnameexport' value='$memberlastnamearray' />
                                        <input type='hidden' name='emailexport' value='$memberphonearray' />
                                        <input type='hidden' name='phoneexport' value='$memberemailarray' />
                                        <input type='hidden' name='num' value='$j' />
```

Comment: Inspect your HTML's `value=` attributes. I suspect you'll see the word `Array` in there, because you attempted to `echo` an array directly as a string representation.  If you need the arrays passed into HTML you will need to `serialize()` and `unserialize()` them.  However, that is really dangerous.  Why not just add them into the session instead of posting them page to page?

Comment: @mike thanks for the reply.  I have a populated list from mysql and from that I have an export button which is what I am working on and I thought it be easiest to just have it be set into a hidden input box and sent over?  If you know better please let me know!

Comment: rename your form field names for arrays to have square brackets at the end , i. e. name="firstnameexport[]" and iterate through all rows, or do serialize unserialize like m. berkowski suggests

Comment: @therao It isn't as simple as that - then it would require looping to display an `<input>` tag for every array element too.

Comment: @DavidBiga Rather than pass all this back to the browser (I'm assuming it is a lot of data since you're doing a CSV export) the more common method is to just run the entire query again and output in CSV format instead of printing to the browser. You don't want to hold such a big dataset in the session, and you don't want to send it down to the browser, so that the browser then has to send it _back_.

Comment: @Therao didnt work....Mike any solutions?

Comment: y, edited comment before saw yours next one

Comment: Mike I am not printing it - Its for my own purpose so i see it works lol

Answer (score 0):

All I had to do was create sessions after the list in the form is populated and if export button is clicked the sessions get sent to export file that will turn it into an excel file.

Thanks for all the help guys!